# Capybara, Javascript and RSpec Integration Tests with :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I have a form that is set to `:remote => true` with 2 submit buttons (One for "Test Connection", one to Create/Update). My controller handles this correctly and renders the correct view based on the button that is clicked.

I have the following integration test to make sure that if the data source can connect, it will show the correct message to the user:

```
describe "Data Source Validation", :js => true do  

  before (:each) do
    @user = create_logged_in_user
  end

  it "returns true when data source is valid" do    
    DataSource.any_instance.stub(:can_connect).and_return(true)    
    visit new_data_source_path
    fill_in "Name", :with => "Example 123"
    fill_in "Host", :with => "myip.example.com"
    select "SQL Server", :from => "Database type"
    fill_in "Database name", :with => "Example"
    fill_in "Username", :with => "user"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
    click_button "Test Connection"
    expect(page).to have_content "Successfully connected to database"
  end

end
```

I am using `gem "capybara-webkit"` and I have defined `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` in spec_helper.rb.

When the test runs, I get the following result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Successfully connected to database"
    expected to find text "Successfully connected to database" in ...
```

**When I view it in Chrome, it works exactly as I expect it to with the correct error message.**

How can I get this test condition to pass?

**data_source_controller.rb** code that is executed for the "Test Connection" method

```
begin      
  if @data_source.valid? && @data_source.can_connect?          
    format.js {render "valid_connection" }          
  else
    format.js {render "invalid_connection" }          
  end
rescue Exception => e
  format.js {render "invalid_connection", locals: {error_msg: e.message} }          
end
```

**EDIT #1**
I switched the javascript driver to :selenium and ran into the same issue. I also attempted to add the "wait_for_ajax" method helper and received an error:

```
 Failure/Error: wait_for_ajax
 Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
   Javascript failed to execute
```

The full error message with just the normal webkit driver and no wait/sleep:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Successfully connected to database"
   expected to find text "Successfully connected to database" in "Dashboard Reports Data Sources Account Create a New Data Source * Name * Host Port * Database type * Database name * Username * Password We encrypt all information in the database. Nothing can be retrieved without the proper credentials and encryption key. Copyright 2013"
```

What I am expecting is the text, "Successfully connected to the database", to show dynamically after "Password" and before "We encrypt all information in the database"

I hope that gives some more insight, I can try to put together a github project to test this out but this is frustrating trying to get this working

Comment: Are you sure this is an AJAX issue, have_content should wait for the content to appear when AJAX requests are pending. Have you tried adding a sleep after click_button "Test Connection" and manually checking the content in the browser window when running the spec? Do you see the controller hit in log/test.log ?

Comment: Have you tried to run it with `:selenium` driver?

Comment: If you look in `log/test.log` after running just this test (and deleting the file before you run it so the only thing in that file is this test's run) do you see the same requests that you see in your development log when this works in Chrome? It looks like your failure message is cut off, I would expect to see something instead of "..." in the failure message that might give a hint of what's on the page.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem of rspec/capybara not detecting ajax changes when things seemed to work fine through a browser.  This is what worked for me:

Add to GemFile

```
gem 'capybara-webkit'
```

Add to host file

```
127.0.0.1  testhost.com
```

Add to spec_helper.rb

```
DEFAULT_HOST = "testhost.com"
DEFAULT_PORT = 7171  

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL  
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  Capybara.default_host = "http://#{DEFAULT_HOST}"
  Capybara.server_port = DEFAULT_PORT
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{DEFAULT_HOST}:#{Capybara.server_port}"

  #fixes issues with capybara not detecting db changes made during tests
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before :each do
    if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end  
end
```

On the test giving issues add a :js => true flag in the describe header like so:

```
 describe 'my test', :js => true do
```

I also could not have the describe block with :js => true nested in other describe blocks, but had to be on its own for it to work,  I think this has to do with switching from rack_test to webkit for the test.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create helper method:

```
def wait_for_ajax
  counter = 0
  while page.execute_script("return $.active").to_i > 0
    counter += 1
    sleep(0.1)
    raise "AJAX request took longer than 5 seconds." if counter >= 50
  end
end
```

And then:

```
click_button "Test Connection"
wait_for_ajax
expect(page).to have_content "Successfully connected to database"
```

Comment: This should not be necessary; [capybara has built in waiting](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends).

Comment: I tried this and I get the following error: `Failure/Error: wait_for_ajax
     Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
       Javascript failed to execute
`

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be an issue with the chrome version,try updating the driver **OR** you can even refer [this](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper)

Comment: The problem is happening with the capybara-webkit driver and works correctly in Chrome.

Comment: well that was a suggestion,you could have commented on my answer rather than giving negative marking @carolclarinet

Comment: I did both, Mike. I don't think an answer that advises trying something unrelated to the problem is productive.