# Rails: Rspec + Capybara + Remote form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec, capybara

I have a quite big rails application whose main view consists of a complex, deeply nested form that is edited by different users along a predefined process flow (user1 inputs some info, user2 some more etc.).

I wrote a very long test using Rspec + Capybara in order to test the whole process, which worked fine until I switched to using a remote form (by setting remote: true).

At this point, I would need to switch between using a js driver and a regular one in order to test different things within the same view (js when submitting, regular driver for everything else), but I cannot seem to find any example of how to do this.

The main issue is all the testing documentation I found assumes you can run separate tests, each with its own driver, just by setting js: true and doing some other changes, but my issue is I need everything to happen within the same test as the sequence of events is key.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you can nest a test using a different capybara driver while keeping changes of the above nested tests; the changes don't stick when changing from say rack_test to webkit or selenium.  I had a similar problem of just getting capybara to detect changes with :remote => true set, ended up getting it to work with webkit driver.  I posted what worked for me here:
[Capybara, Javascript and RSpec Integration Tests with :remote => true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083321/capybara-javascript-and-rspec-integration-tests-with-remote-true/20021787#20021787)

You may just want to refactor out the steps needed to be done before the test with a remote form into a method that you can just call in a before block to keep your code clean.